# Updating Database records not working in c# winforms and MSAccess

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I'm using the following code to update Product details in the MS Access database in my WinForms Application but although I get the success message, the data is not updated

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb";

            String Bcode = txtCode.Text;
            String Pname = textBox22.Text;
            String Pcost = txtPcost2.Text;
            String Pprice = txtPprice2.Text;

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Products SET Pname = @Pname, Pcost = @Pcost, Pprice = @Pprice WHERE Bcode = @Bcode");
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bcode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Bcode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Pname;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pcost", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Pcost;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pprice", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Pprice;

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
            }
```

Comment: As explained in the duplicate, the parameters order matter. By the way, do you really store Cost and Price in text columns?

Comment: Thanks Steve, cost and price are set to currency in MS Access

Comment: Then use the appropriate type when you prepare the parameter (and convert the value to decimal)

Comment: Side note. After calling the ExecuteNonQuery, display the SUCCESS message only if the return of ExecuteNonQuery is not zero.